# Overload angle brackets in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overloading

Pretty odd question but is it possible to overload the meaning of certain bracket types e.g. `<, >, [, ] and |` in Python.  For instance if I have some object instances `MyObj1` and `MyObj2` could I design something whereby `<MyObj1 | MyObj2 >` was understood as either a method call in `MyObj1`?

I think it probably can't/shouldn't be done but I thought I'd ask!

Comment: Uhhhhh... *Why?* EDIT: Also, no it's not possible unless you fork CPython and write the code yourself to support it.

Comment: Although you can overload operators, you cannot change their [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). Both `<` and `>` are binary operators that require two operands, even if you overload them.

Comment: Yeah I thought it might have been a bit far out but by way of a quick explaination I wanted to write something to compute Bra-Kets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) conveniently and in a syntactically similar fashion

Answer (score 4):

No.  The only operator overloading that is allowed in Python is changing the runtime semantics of pre-existing operators.  The syntax `<MyObj1 | MyObj2 >` would involve either making `<` and `>` into unary operators (one prefix, one postfix) or making them both into a single "circumfix" operator.  As they are currently both binary infix operators, such a change cannot be done.